# Django does not reset module variables during multiple requests

Tags: python, django, django-views

It seems that module variables live as long as a process lives and do not reset until the process restarts.

Here is my code which i expect to behave another way that it behaves now:

I have a module responsible for various SEO features like breadcrumbs and title, file fancy/utils.py:

```
class Seo:
    title = ['project name']
```

Later in my views i can add items to Seo.title (news.views for example):

```
from fancy.utils import Seo

def index(request, news_id):
    title.append('some specific title')
    ...
```

The point is that the variable *Seo.title* actually does not reset at every request, so it continues to append items to itself and it looks very strange to me (as i came from PHP).

Eventually if i hit F5 at the same page the title always grows up to smth huge and long.

What's going on and what should i do?

thanks

Comment: Why do you need a class here at all? Seems like a dict would be a better solution.

Comment: Explain what? You should explain why you think you need a class here. A local dictionary makes much more sense.

Comment: I need to modify this Seo.title variable from anywhere in the code, not in views only. So this variable must be accessed globally, that's the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems from your comments that you have totally misunderstood the execution model of Django.

You can't have data local to the request that you can somehow access from anywhere in the code. If you need data associated with a particular request, you should store it somewhere where the code running that request can retrieve it: perhaps in the session, perhaps in a temporary dictionary added onto the request object itself. Anything you store globally will be, well, global: visible to any request running inside the same process.

Comment: Ok, now i understand this (btw, it would be nice if you share some links about this Python behaviour as i could not find anything about it in django docs).

So what do you think is the best approach to implement title tag functionality (not exactly title tag, may be some other related stuff)?

Answer (score 1):

Your `title` is a class attribute not an `instance` attribute. If you want to preserve settings across multiple requests you could keep a reference to it in the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/).

e.g.

```
class Seo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = ['project name']

...

def index(request, news_id):
    seo = request.session.get('seo', Seo())
    seo.title.append('some specific title')
```

Comment: >If you want to preserve settings across multiple requests you could keep a reference to it in the session.

No, i just want these variables be reset on each request. I don't need to keep smth between requests and also i don't need to have an instance of Seo class just to modify its variables.

Are there any other ways to do that? I need an elegant solution please.

Comment: You cannot do that with a class attribute. The attribute value remains for the lifetime of the process. You could just create new context variable: title = Seo.title + ['some specific title']

Comment: So are all the class attributes shared between requests? What about global variables, are they shared too?

Comment: This is a feature of Python. A global variable is indeed global.

Comment: Ok, but i need this variable be accessed globally (from any place in the code). And, of course, the will be no 'request' variable defined to get to the session.

Comment: You need some form of persistant storage.